# MS Access 2013 SQL Query LEFT JOIN

Tags: ms-access, join

```
FROM (((Project 
INNER JOIN MDS ON Project.PID=MDS.PID) 
INNER JOIN PLocation ON Project.PID = PLocation.PID) 
INNER JOIN Site ON PLocation.ACode = Site.ACode) AS [Prim] 
LEFT JOIN ((Procurement INNER JOIN MagicT ON Procurement.PRNum = MagicT.PRNum) 
INNER JOIN DO ON DO.DoNum = MagicT.DONum) AS [Prim2] ON Prim.PRNum = Prim2.PRNum
```

Hey guys. So the above from statement is giving me an error:

> Syntax error in from clause

Funny thing is when I make the `LEFT JOIN` an `INNER JOIN` it runs fine, but sadly that isn't what I want. I read that I had to rename the inner queries and join them using their new names but unfortunately I do not think I did it properly.

Comment: I believe you have nothing related to mysql. remove the tag please then

Comment: In Access, left join = left outer join. In either case, it did not work.

Comment: table aliases belong after the table names, not after the join criteria.  As PRIM and as PRIM2 seem to be in the incorrect locations.  additionally... it seems like you're trying to alias the association of two tables... again not proper syntax... if you need the tables to be grouped together use an inline view `INNER JOIN (SELECT * from table left join other) as Prim`

Comment: My suggestion would be to add each join one at a time.  If it runs, add the next one.  Keep doing that until it errors, and see if you can reason through why the error happened.  It's hard to tell without knowing anything about table structure or data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also discovered one of my issues here, is that in Access, you can have a left or right join nested inside an inner join but CANNOT have an inner join inside a left or right join. Rewriting the query to not include these joins inside the inner joins has solved the issue.

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this... using two inline views.  but you should be able to do this with just ()'s in Access...  however if you have same named columns in each of Prim/prim2 tables, this will present with errors you may have to spell out each of the column names needed in the inline views.

```
FROM (SELECT * FROM Project 
INNER JOIN MDS ON Project.PID=MDS.PID
INNER JOIN PLocation ON Project.PID = PLocation.PID
INNER JOIN Site ON PLocation.ACode = Site.ACode) PRIM
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * from Procurement 
           INNER JOIN MagicT ON Procurement.PRNum = MagicT.PRNum
           INNER JOIN DO ON DO.DoNum = MagicT.DONum) PRIM2
  ON Prim.PRNUM = Prim2.PRNUM
```

--- maybe... in access the ()'s will handle the outer join  but I don't know what table PRNUM is sourced from in (project, mds, plocation,site)  so project is a guess...

```
FROM Project 
INNER JOIN MDS ON Project.PID=MDS.PID
INNER JOIN PLocation ON Project.PID = PLocation.PID
INNER JOIN Site ON PLocation.ACode = Site.ACode
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * from Procurement 
           INNER JOIN MagicT ON Procurement.PRNum = MagicT.PRNum
           INNER JOIN DO ON DO.DoNum = MagicT.DONum) PRIM2
  ON Project.PRNUM = Prim2.PRNUM
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically have

```
FROM Subquery1 LEFT JOIN Subquery2
```

but your subqueries don't have SELECT in them.
I think it should be:

```sql
FROM 
(SELECT Prim.PRNum FROM
    (((Project 
    INNER JOIN MDS ON Project.PID=MDS.PID) 
    INNER JOIN PLocation ON Project.PID = PLocation.PID) 
    INNER JOIN Site ON PLocation.ACode = Site.ACode) 
AS [Prim]) 

LEFT JOIN 

(SELECT Prim2.PRNum FROM
    ((Procurement INNER JOIN MagicT ON Procurement.PRNum = MagicT.PRNum) 
    INNER JOIN DO ON DO.DoNum = MagicT.DONum) 
AS [Prim2])

ON Prim.PRNum = Prim2.PRNum
```

(edit: a little too late...)